# significant difference in dax language

Tags: powerbi, dax

I would like to calculate the significant difference of the total percentage that I calculate it like this:

```
D2Porc = 

DIVIDE(
SUM(_WEIGHTS[Ponde]),
CALCULATE(SUM(_WEIGHTS[Ponde]), ALL(Filtro_D2[Value])))
```

then I create a matrix in power bi where I pull the Value column from a table called Filter_Wave and put it as columns and as a row I put Value from a table called Filter_D2 in value I put that value D2Porc but now I need to get the difference by column since filter_wave value contains two values ​​wave 1 and wave 2 I want to do the same calculation dc2porc but only to the data value filter_D2 filtered wave 1 and another I calculate the filtered by wa go 2 and finally do a subtraction

I attempted to provide DAX formulas to calculate "D2Porc_Filtered" based on the information provided by the user. I expected that the provided DAX code would accurately filter the data and calculate the desired result. However, due to the complexity of the filtering requirements and the structure of the tables, some of my initial attempts resulted in errors. After adjusting the code and considering the specific table structures, I provided a revised DAX formula that should work correctly for calculating "D2Porc_Filtered" based on the filtering conditions mentioned.